# Keyed lookup on data.table without 'with'

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I have a `data.table` structure like so (except mine is really huge):

```
dt <- data.table(x=1:5, y=3:7, key='x')
```

I want to look up rows in that structure by *another* variable whose name is `x` (notice - the same as the name of the key of `dt`):

```
x <- 3:4
dt2 <- dt[ J(x) ]
```

This doesn't work, because the lookup sees the column name first, and the local variable is obscured:

```
dt2
#    x y
# 1: 1 3
# 2: 2 4
# 3: 3 5
# 4: 4 6
# 5: 5 7
```

I thought about the `with` argument for `[.data.table`, but that only applies to the `j` argument, not the `i` argument.

Is there something similar for the `i` argument?

If not, such a thing would be handy whenever I'm using a local variable and I don't know the complete list of column names in `dt`, to avoid conflicts.

Comment: There is an item in the NEWS for 1.8.2 that suggests a `..()` syntax is planned, to evaluate in the calling frame. It doesn't appear to be within `1.8.7`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an item in the NEWS for 1.8.2 that suggests a `..()` syntax will be added at some point, allowing this

> New DT[.(...)] syntax (in the style of package plyr) is identical to
>           DT[list(...)], DT[J(...)] and DT[data.table(...)]. We plan to add ..(), too, so
>           that .() and ..() are analogous to the file system's ./ and ../; i.e., .()
>           evaluates within the frame of DT and ..() in the parent scope.

In the mean time, you can `get` from the appropriate environment

```
dt[J(get('x', envir = parent.frame(3)))]
##    x y
## 1: 3 5
## 2: 4 6
```

or you could `eval` the whole call to `list(x)` or `J(x)`

```
dt[eval(list(x))]
dt[eval(J(x))]
dt[eval(.(x))]
```

Comment: You must be using a different `dt` or a different `x`.

Comment: Ah, yes my `x <- 2:3` (I could have sworn I copied from the question, (although it was in the 5 min grace period)

Comment: Thanks @mnel, it looks like this uses an indexed join and `merge()` doesn't, so I'm going to switch my accepted answer to yours.  I previously tried `I()` instead of `eval()` and got a lot of warnings, I didn't think of trying `eval()`.

Comment: @mnel, I'm wondering where the 3 in `parent.frame(3)` came from?  (As opposed to 2)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta --Trial and error (2 was my initial thought). It would depend on how the i argument is parsed within [.data.table and as such may change in future versions.

Comment: @mnel, interesting.. I would have thought 1 for `J` and 1 for `DT`.  Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @RicardoSaporta and perhaps one for get too.

Answer (score 2):

New answer, now that I think I understand what was requested:

```
> X <- data.table(x=x)
> merge(dt, X)
   x y
1: 3 6
2: 4 7
```

Comment: you could save two keystrokes by `data.table(x)`

Comment: I just realized (from benchmarking) this doesn't use the index on `dt`, so unfortunately this won't work.  I thought I read somewhere that `merge` was supposed to use the index when possible though?

Answer (score 2):

Setting a key is not required and it's faster:

```
dt[eval(dt[, x %in% ..x])]

   x y
1: 3 5
2: 4 6
```

Benchmark with the previously posted answers

```
microbenchmark(dt[eval(dt[, x %in% ..x])],
               dt[J(get('x', parent.frame(3)))],
               dt[eval(list(x))],
               dt[eval(J(x))],
               dt[eval(.(x))],
               merge(dt, data.table(x)),
               times = 100L)

Unit: microseconds
                                  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
      dt[eval(dt[, x %in% ..x])]  486.1  500.60  518.529  503.70  512.65 1238.0   100
dt[J(get("x", parent.frame(3)))]  837.3  853.25  891.424  860.00  868.30 1675.3   100
               dt[eval(list(x))]  831.8  842.70  929.521  851.95  859.85 3878.3   100
                  dt[eval(J(x))]  833.8  845.50  948.535  856.00  870.00 4599.2   100
                  dt[eval(.(x))]  828.6  846.40  871.054  851.75  859.35 1985.6   100
        merge(dt, data.table(x)) 1766.0 1804.70 1907.617 1819.95 1870.95 3123.1   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some benchmarking results, by request.

`dt` is a 53080731 x 5 `data.table` object, keyed by a numeric column with around 100 unique values, fairly evenly distributed.  `x` is a vector containing 5 of those values.

```
library(microbenchmark)
> mb <- microbenchmark(
+     dt[eval(J(x))],
+     merge(dt, data.table(x)),
+     times=10
+ )
> mb
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr      min       lq    median       uq      max neval
           dt[eval(J(x))]  127.324  127.549  133.5305  154.410  159.433    10
 merge(dt, data.table(x)) 5028.349 5083.792 5129.6590 5170.451 5250.255    10
```

@Tyler, if you can assist me with how to use `qdap::lookup()` for this case with multiple columns, I can add that too.