# keyed lookup in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

here's an example of a data.table keyed lookup being called from another data.table while performing an aggregation.  The code fails since the variable ids in the latter data.table and the key var names in the former table are the same.   The error that I get is `Error in rep(0, tot.dt[list(var, y)][["cnt"]] - .N) :  invalid 'times' argument`.  To make it work, I have to change the variable names in one of the tables.

```
N <- 10000
data.dt <- data.table(obs=sample(1001:2000,N,replace=T), var=sample(101:200,N,replace=T))
data.dt <- unique(data.dt)[, value:=runif(.N)][]

obsmap.dt <- unique(data.dt[,.(obs)])[, y:=round(runif(.N)>.9)][]
data.dt <- merge(data.dt, obsmap.dt, by="obs")[, .(var,y,value)]

#DOES NOT WORK
tot.dt <- merge(CJ(var=unique(data.dt[["var"]]), y=c(0,1)), obsmap.dt[, .(cnt=.N), y], by="y")[, .(var,y,cnt)]
setkey(tot.dt, var, y)

tiles <- seq(0,100,10)
data.dt[, as.list(quantile(c(rep(0,tot.dt[.(var,y)][["cnt"]]-.N),value), 
    probs=tiles/100, names=FALSE, type=3)), by=.(var,y)]

#WORKS
setkey(setnames(tot.dt, c("var1","y1","cnt")), var1, y1)

data.dt[, as.list(quantile(c(rep(0,tot.dt[.(var,y)][["cnt"]]-.N),value), 
    probs=tiles/100, names=FALSE, type=3)), by=.(var,y)]
```

This question is related to [Keyed lookup on data.table without 'with'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102068/keyed-lookup-on-data-table-without-with)  The big difference being scope of the calls.  Is it possible to do this without the renaming?

Comment: What were you expecting from `tot.dt[.(var,y)]`? If you just want to sort, you could use `order(var,y)`...

Comment: It is used to look up the value of `cnt` given `var` and `y`. That value helps to pad the appropriate number of zeroes so that quantile is computed correctly.