# data.table := assignments when variable has same name as a column

Tags: r, data.table

I found this strange behavior when assigning a value to a position. If the variable has the same name as a column it thinks we are talking about the column:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(a = integer(1))
a <- 18
dt1[1, a:=a]
```

Result:

> ```
> > dt1
>    a
> 1: 0
> ```

We can avoid this by using different names:

```
dt2 <- data.table(a = integer(1))
b <- 18
dt2[1, a:=b]
```

Result:

> ```
> >dt2
>     a
> 1: 18
> ```

But is there another way to do this without changing the name of the variable? I read about `.() ..()` notation but I'm not sure whether I can use it here, something like:

```
dt1 <- data.table(a = integer(1))
a <- 18
dt1[1, a:=..(a)]

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function ".."
```

Comment: where did you read about `..()`?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102068/keyed-lookup-on-data-table-without-with/15102156#15102156

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always use `get`, which allows you to specify the environment:

```
dt1[1, a := get("a", envir = .GlobalEnv)]
#    a
#1: 18
```

Or just:

```
a <- 42
dt1[1, a := .GlobalEnv$a]
#    a
#1: 42
```

Comment: @Henrik isn't `..a` looking for a column named `42`?

Comment: For me, `..a` also captures `a` in the global env: e.g.  `dt1[1, a := ..a]`

Comment: @Marcinthebox Yeah, this answer was written long before that syntax had been added to data.table.