# Distinguishing between an external variable and a column in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

How do I get the following code to recognize the second `a` in `dt[a == a,]` as an external variable with value 3?

```
a <- 3
dt <- data.table(a = seq(5), b = rnorm(5))
dt[a==a,]
```

Expected output should be the same as the output from `dt[a==3,]`.

EDIT:

I'm aware that there's a solution available here: [Subsetting data.table using variables with same name as column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658893/subsetting-data-table-using-variables-with-same-name-as-column)

But the answer is from 4 years ago and the first comment mentions that the package maintainers are aware of this scoping issue and are working to fix it. So, is there now a straightforward way to address this?

Comment: I think the recent ones are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738499/data-table-assignments-when-variable-has-same-name-as-a-column) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256904/datatable-column-name-is-the-same-as-global-environment-value)

Comment: @akrun You can click the edit button on the "already has an answer" box to add more links (a feature added a year or so ago, I think)