# data.table - subsetting based on variable whose name is a column, too

Tags: r, data.table

This may be a bit weird but I frequently face this situation when working with `data.table` within functions whose argument I am using for filtering.

Imagine you have a variable whose value you want to compare a `data.table`'s column to and do filtering. What if the name of the variable is the same as the column's name?

Example and things I've tried:

```
DT <- data.table(mtcars)
cyl <- 4
# intended: filter rows where column "cyl" equals the value of variable cyl

# this does not work
DT[cyl == (cyl)]
# this does not work either
DT[cyl == `cyl`]
```

Comment: Related posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102068/keyed-lookup-on-data-table-without-with) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658893/subsetting-data-table-using-variables-with-same-name-as-column)

Comment: @Henrik yup these ones :)

Comment: @paljenczy that's because typically and certainly in r "filtering" is called "subsetting" :)

Comment: Thanks, changed the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Data.table runs in the environment of the data table itself right, so you might need to specify where you want to get the value from

```
DT[cyl == get("cyl", envir = parent.frame())]
```

Comment: does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 6):

Just specify the scoping:

`DT[cyl == globalenv()$cyl]`